# Can I use a Quadratic model ax^2+bx+c for nonlinear regression using levenberg?

Tags: regression

I am working on data fitting. I need to fit a surface. I used two methods.

1) Polynomial regression with two variable. (linear / OSL)
and 
2) Quadratic model a*x^2+b*x+c.

My question is Can I use a Quadratic model ax^2+bx+c for nonlinear regression using levenberg. Since I already implemented it

Answer (score 0):

Yes, with two considerations:

1) With linear regression you are mathematically certain to be at the minimum least-squared solution, within the arithmetic resolution of the computer you are using.  This is not certain with non-linear fitting algorithms.

2) Most nonlinear solvers have default initial parameters of all 1.0 *if* you do not supply initial values yourself.  This can lead to the nonlinear fitting algorithm not reaching a desired minimum least-squared solution, but a local rather than global minimum.  Linear solvers do not need initial parameters.